# Unable to successfully divide the JSON file using python in DataBricks

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, databricks

Hi I am writing a DATABRICKS Python code which picks huge JSON file and divide into two part. Which means from index 0 or "reporting_entity_name" till index 3 or "version" on one file and from index 4 in other file till the end. Though it successfully divides the file from index 1 of the json file but when i provide index 0 it fails and says

```
Datasource does not support writing empty or nested empty schemas. Please make sure the data schema has at least one or more column(s).
```

Here is the SAMPLE Data of large JSON file.

```
{
  "reporting_entity_name": "launcher",
  "reporting_entity_type": "launcher",
  "last_updated_on": "2020-08-27",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "in_network": [
    {
      "negotiation_arrangement": "ffs",
      "name": "Boosters",
      "billing_code_type": "CPT",
      "billing_code_type_version": "2020",
      "billing_code": "27447",
      "description": "Boosters On Demand",
      "negotiated_rates": [
        {
          "provider_groups": [
            {
              "npi": [
                0
              ],
              "tin": {
                "type": "ein",
                "value": "11-1111111"
              }
            }
          ],
          "negotiated_prices": [
            {
              "negotiated_type": "negotiated",
              "negotiated_rate": 123.45,
              "expiration_date": "2022-01-01",
              "billing_class": "organizational"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the python code.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, col
import itertools

# Read the JSON file from Databricks storage
df_json = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json("/mnt/BigData_JSONFiles/SampleDatafilefrombigfile.json")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "false")

# Convert the dataframe to a dictionary
data = df_json.toPandas().to_dict()

# Split the data into two parts
d1 = dict(itertools.islice(data.items(), 1))
d2 = dict(itertools.islice(data.items(), 1, len(data.items())))

# Convert the first part of the data back to a dataframe
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([d1])

# Write the first part of the data to a JSON file in Databricks storage
df1.write.format("json").save("/mnt/BigData_JSONFiles/SampleDatafilefrombigfile_detail.json")

# Convert the second part of the data back to a dataframe
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([d2])

# Write the second part of the data to a JSON file in Databricks storage
df2.write.format("json").save("/mnt/BigData_JSONFiles/SampleDatafilefrombigfile_header.json")
```

Here is the output of the two files. In the output file you can see in the detail file it should only contains the data of "in_network" but it also have the 0 index data which is "reporting_entity_name" which shouldnt be in detail file it should be in header file.

```
{
"in_network": [
    {
      "negotiation_arrangement": "ffs",
      "name": "Boosters",
      "billing_code_type": "CPT",
      "billing_code_type_version": "2020",
      "billing_code": "27447",
      "description": "Boosters On Demand",
      "negotiated_rates": [
        {
          "provider_groups": [
            {
              "npi": [
                0
              ],
              "tin": {
                "type": "ein",
                "value": "11-1111111"
              }
            }
          ],
          "negotiated_prices": [
            {
              "negotiated_type": "negotiated",
              "negotiated_rate": 123.45,
              "expiration_date": "2022-01-01",
              "billing_class": "organizational"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},"negotiation_arrangement":"ffs"}]}}
```

The output of the Headerfile which starts from 1 index and gives the output.

```
{"reporting_entity_type": "launcher",
  "last_updated_on": "2020-08-27",
  "version": "1.0.0"}
```

Kindly please help me in this error.

A guidance on code will be helpful.

Here is the screenshot of large json file which is exact copy of the file attached above I increased the cluster from 2 gb to 8gb. But the error is same also dict inside in_network occurs 714 times in the file does. But why it is failing in the big file. If it is exactly same.
I change the code line of the answer to this also

```
df_network=df_json.select(df_json.columns[714:])
```

[image]

Here is the TraceBack

```
AnalysisException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-863551447189973> in <cell line: 13>()
     11 df_version=df_json.select(df_json.columns[:1])
     12 
---> 13 df_network.write.format("json").save("/mnt/BigData_JSONFiles/2022-10_040_05C0_in-network-rates_2_of_2_detail.json")
     14 df_version.write.format("json").save("/mnt/BigData_JSONFiles/2022-10_040_05C0_in-network-rates_2_of_2_header.json")
     15 display(df_network)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/instrumentation_utils.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     46             start = time.perf_counter()
     47             try:
---> 48                 res = func(*args, **kwargs)
     49                 logger.log_success(
     50                     module_name, class_name, function_name, time.perf_counter() - start, signature

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in save(self, path, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
    966             self._jwrite.save()
    967         else:
--> 968             self._jwrite.save(path)
    969 
    970     @since(1.4)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1319 
   1320         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321         return_value = get_return_value(
   1322             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1323 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    200                 # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
    201                 # JVM exception message.
--> 202                 raise converted from None
    203             else:
    204                 raise

AnalysisException: 
Datasource does not support writing empty or nested empty schemas.
Please make sure the data schema has at least one or more column(s).
```

Comment: You are welcome. I hope you will get helpful answers soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced your code and got below results for one file.

```
{"last_updated_on":{"0":"2020-08-27"},"reporting_entity_name":{"0":"launcher"},"reporting_entity_type":{"0":"launcher"},"version":{"0":"1.0.0"}}
```

[image]

The inner `0` key might be due to the usage of dictionary and pandas.

**As your JSON has the same structure, you can try the below workaround to divide the JSON** using `select` rather than converting into dictionary.

This is the Original Dataframe from JSON file.

[image]

So, use `select` to generate the required JSON files.

```
df_network=df_json.select(df_json.columns[:1])
df_version=df_json.select(df_json.columns[1:])
display(df_network)
display(df_version)
```

**Dataframes:**

[image]

**Result after writing to JSON files:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: But When i tried it in huge JSON, It throws the error which is stated in the down answer.

Comment: If it works for the small JSON file and not working for the large files and displaying correctly, then I think it is up to the performance of the cluster.

Comment: Thank you today i increased cluster size I have edited the question in the last and attached a screen shot of large json file also as I cannot copy the whole file. I am getting the error stated above